# SQL problem to select value based on priority

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have one table Named **Table1**

| UniqueId | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Second | abc |
| 2 | A | First | def |
| 3 | A | Second | ghi |

This Is **Table2**

| Rank | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | First |
| 2 | Second |
| 3 | Third |

Now I have to select value like below, condition will be on Column C of Table1 and based on Table2
Like in above table1 column C has three values (Second, First, First), but First in ranked superior then second as per Table2 hence my output should look like before.
Basically I have to select the superior one based on ranking. if Column C Table1 has (Third, Second, Second) so I want to select second, if Column C Table1 has (Third, Second, First) so I want to select First. if all the three value is same then that will be selected.

| UniqueId | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Second | abc | First |
| 2 | A | First | def | First |
| 3 | A | Second | ghi | First |

I have searched a lot but I don't know how that select statement will look like.

Comment: Are you really using SQL Server 2012, it's well past time to upgrade if so. Hint - you could use analytical window functions.

Comment: @Stu Am using SQL Server 2019

Comment: Do you really understand what you have written? For example, what does it mean "Like in above table1 column C has three values (Second, First, First)," ? Where does those values come from? Probably your explanation do not match the sample.

Comment: @stu can you provide me how can I use that as i am a beginner and trying to learn.

Comment: @cetin-basoz brother it was simple I mean to say that Column 3 has 3 different rows which has Second, First and First in row1, row2 and row 3 respectively. rest other points were assumptions that it could have Second, First and First in row1, row2 and row 3 respectively.

Comment: I saw Second, First, Second in the example, not Second, First, First. So I wasn't sure if you were really referring to that sample or saying those values would occur as a comma separated value in a single row. It is not clear what you mean 3 rows as well. Would the table always have 3 rows, if not then how do you differentiate between the 3 rows blocks (@Stu assumed you were partitioning the data by columnB - you gave no clue though, it is a wild guess which is likely correct anyway).

Comment: @CetinBasoz First of all Thankyou for your feedback and sorry that I made a mess in asking question, but fortunately Stu understood and answered what I actually needed. With the time I will learn how to frame question hopefully. I am just starting my career.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the analytical function *first_value* here:

```
select t.*,
  First_Value(t.c) over(partition by t.b order by r.rank) as NewRank
from t
join ranks r on r.value = t.c
order by UniqueId;
```

Comment: This works for  me. Thank you.